# Javascript http get success function capturing error response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am making a http request to a url which is returing a `500 error` response(This is the expected behavior). But this is error is getting captured in the success function instead of error function.

```
$http.get("myUrl")
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
    .function (error) {
        // Handle error here
    });
```

Please help in understanding this and the correct way to use this.

Comment: What library are you using? Shouldn't that be `).error(function()...)`?

Comment: @Barmar "...then(...).error is not a function" this is the error I am getting now

Comment: What library is this? It's not jQuery. Is it Angular?

Comment: @Barmar Its angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an interceptor in my application which was causing the problem.
All my error responses were intercepted and returned without a status. Below is the code.

```
return {
        'responseError': function(config) {

            if(config.status===401){
              //Do Something

              return config;
            }

          return config;
        }
    }
```

Changing the return statement to `return $q.reject(config);` started returning the correct status.

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:

```
$http.get("myUrl")
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
    ,function (error) {
        // Handle error here
    });
```

Or

```
$http.get("myUrl")
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch (function(error) {
        // Handle error here
    });
```

Comment: 500 internal server error still comes in the first function

Comment: Is your REST api returning status as 500? Do you have any angular intercepter which handkes the Ajax calls?

Answer (score 1):

If this is angulars $http, it's supposed to be something like this:

```
$http.get("myUrl")
  .then(
    function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      // Handle error here
    }
  );
```

You want two functions as your arguments to then(). The first is your successCallback, the second your errorCallback.

As an alternative you may add an catch() to your promise chain. Which is easier to read and prevents errors like yours.